# Is `export { foo as default }` valid ES2015?

Tags: javascript, syntax, language-lawyer, ecmascript-6, specifications

I received an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/54) about my ES2015 module import/export validating plugin for ESLint not recognizing the `default` export in the following syntax:

```
export { 
    foo as default,
    bar
}
```

where my plugin will lint the following (equivalent?) syntax no problem:

```
export default foo;
export const bar = ..;
```

Both [Babel](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=true&code=export%20%7B%20foo%20as%20default%20%7D) and [Esprima](http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html?code=%2F%2F%20Life%2C%20Universe%2C%20and%20Everything%0Avar%20answer%20%3D%206%20*%207%3B%0A%0Aexport%20%7B%20answer%20as%20default%20%7D%3B%0A) parse similar syntax without errors, and this works for code using Babel on both ends (import and export).

However, I'm not convinced the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-exports-static-semantics-early-errors) allows the former `export { x as default }` form:

> For each `IdentifierName` `n` in `ReferencedBindings` of `ExportClause` : It is a Syntax Error if StringValue of n is a ReservedWord or if the StringValue of n is one of: "implements", "interface", "let", "package", "private", "protected", "public", "static", or "yield".

`ReservedWord` [does include `default`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-reserved-words), though I think one could argue that `ReferencedBindings` is referring [specifically to the module-local identifier names](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-exports-static-semantics-exportedbindings) that are being *exported* (i.e. `foo`) and not the exported name itself.

It also generally seems like a weird thing to be able to export reserved words; Babel will happily also allow something like

```
// ./foo.js
export { foo as yield }
// ./mod.js
import { yield as nonReservedIdentifier } from './foo'
```

So, in summary:  is `export { foo as default }` a valid way to export a default in ES2015?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, [*ReferencedBindings*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-static-semantics-referencedbindings) refers only to the first IdentifierName. So

```
export { default as something } // or
export { default }
```

is invalid, but

```
export { something as default }
```

is not. ESLint will need a fix here.

Comment: In this case, though, is `default` a named export named `default` or the actual `default` export?

Comment: I guess the [import spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-static-semantics-importentriesformodule) suggests it is both.

Comment: Yes, the default export is just an exported binding with the name `default`. It's both so to say, except that there's special syntax for exporting/importing default exports, and `default` is an invalid local identifier otherwise.

Comment: @BenMosher It's the same difference. The default export is just an export named `default` and is special-cased with some syntactic sugar.

Comment: @Bergi Why, because of the early error semantics at 15.2.3.1? Those don't apply to that syntax.

Comment: @Bergi It's definitely confusing. Had the same conversation with someone else a couple weeks ago where they read it, concluded it's valid, then talked themself out of it because of those early error semantics (overlooking in the end that it doesn't apply to this case).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's valid. I'll break it down.

1. :

   ```
   export { foo as default }
   ```

   This matches the following productions (from least to most specific):

   ```
   export ExportClause
   ExportClause : { ExportsList }
   ExportsList : ExportSpecifier
   ExportSpecifier : IdentifierName as IdentifierName
   ```
2. Then you have the [early error semantics](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-exports-static-semantics-early-errors):

   > 15.2.3.1 Static Semantics: Early Errors
   >
   > `ExportDeclaration : export ExportClause ;`
   >
   > For each `IdentifierName` `n` in `ReferencedBindings` of `ExportClause` : It is a Syntax Error if `StringValue` of `n` is a `ReservedWord`...

   These apply to any productions matching `export ExportClause`, including your example syntax. This invokes the `ReferencedBindings` algorithm.
3. The [`ReferencedBindings`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-static-semantics-referencedbindings) algorithm that applies to that most specific production matched by this syntax is:

   > `ExportSpecifier : IdentifierName as IdentifierName`
   >
   > Return a `List` containing the first `IdentifierName`.

So you see that the restriction regarding `ReservedWord` and the other listed values is only applied to the `foo` part of the syntax in your example.