# ES6, how can you export an imported module in a single line?

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, import

I'd like to the following but with a single line, if possible:

- `import Module from './Module/Module;'`
- `export Module;`

I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

- `export Module from './Module/Module;`

Comment: See also [Is there any one-line analog in ES6 for ES5 `module.exports = require('./inner.js')`?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32229947/1048572) and [Is `export { foo as default }` valid ES6?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33155785/1048572)

Answer (score 287, accepted):

```
export {default as Module} from './Module/Module';
```

is the standard ES6 way, as long as you don't need `Module` to also be available inside the module doing the exporting.

```
export Module from './Module/Module';
```

is a proposed ESnext way to do it, but that only works if you've enabled it in Babel for now.

Comment: It worked great, however, it seems like Webpack doesn't like this, giving a notification that the `component` is now read-only and unable to be hot reloaded. Very strange!

Comment: perfect, this should be the accepted answer. (if webpack hot reload doesn't like that's a problem in that tool or it's HMR plugin.)

Comment: If anyone is wondering which babel plugin it is, it is `export-extensions` here - http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-export-extensions/

Comment: @loganfsmyth is there a way to export the above as default?

Comment: @abhishek-kdm `export { default as default } from` or `export { default } from`

Comment: Problem seems to be if Module is commonjs module with only default export and you do not want to use it inside current module with this statement, but still want to exported.. I have utilities module which is reexporting some methods from lodash, but they are commonjs modules, only option seems to be using lodash-es npm package :/

Comment: Also I have just found that using `export {default as Module} from './Module/Module';` Module is not defined in current file ‍♂️

Comment: What's the best way to also use that export in the same file? Edit: just have duplicate lines with import & export I guess.

Comment: @kano Yes you'd want to separate them.

Answer (score 45):

I don't know why but just this works for me :

components/index.js:

```
import Component from './Component';
import Component2 from './Component2';
import Component3 from './Component3';
import Component4 from './Component4';

export {Component, Component2, Component3, Component4};
```

I import the exports like this :

```
import {Component, Component2, Component3, Component4} from '../components';
```

Comment: ⚠ this method kills three shaking

Comment: How can this be adjusted to not kill tree shaking?

Answer (score 38):

Please note you can also re-export everything from a module:

```
export * from './Module/Module';
```

Comment: This wildcard syntax will only work on files with named exports.  If the file only has a single default export, you'll get the error "No named exports found in module".

Answer (score 21):

For React Native components this syntax works for me:

```
export {default} from 'react-native-swiper';
```

Comment: This works for me for React (not Native) when I wish to re-export an imported default. I use this in index.js files that don't apply any HOCs to my 'pure' components

Answer (score 0):

```
// Service
// ...
export const paymentService = new PaymentService()

// Entry services/index.js file
export * from './paymentService'

// use it like
import { paymentService } from './services/'
```

Answer (score -3):

So, I've found this to work quite well for the immediate export functionality of having an `index.js` at the root of the `components` directory for easy referencing:

```
import Component from './Component/Component'
import ComponentTwo from './ComponentTwo/ComponentTwo'

module.exports = {
  Component,
  ComponentTwo
};
```

You need to use `module.exports`.

Comment: Keep in mind that since this is partially CommonJS modules, this will only work specifically in Babel and will fail if you attempt to use it in a real ES6 module once support for them lands in more environments, and will likely stop working in future versions of Babel.

Comment: Correct. Intermingling commonJS & es6 import / export in Babel 6 breaks. Babel5 allowed / reinforced this incorrect behavior. In your example, `Component` will no longer be a reference to your exported component, but instead will be an object, with your instance reference living on `Component.default`

Comment: Anybody know how to do this without using `module.exports` ?  I like this method of packaging a bunch of components into an `index.js` but can't figure out the syntax.  `import x from 'x'; import y from 'y';  export default {x, y};` then `import {x} from xy;` doesn't work (and I can't figure out why not)

Comment: Alex, did you try `export {x, y}` instead?

Comment: This answer is not es6. It's a non-EcamScript platform. -1