# How to load array of handlebar templates through web pack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, handlebars.js

Is there a way to compile directory of templates and store in array object using `Webpack`?

Explanation: I am now using list of handlebars templates. I precompile the list of templates using `handlebars compiler` in `gulp`.

```
gulp.src('client/src/templates/**/*.hbs')
  .pipe(gulp_handlebars({
      handlebars: handlebars,
       compilerOptions:{
        knownHelpers: helpers,
        knownHelpersOnly:true}
      }))
      .pipe(wrap('Handlebars.template(<%= contents %>)'))
      .pipe(declare({
        namespace: 'appname.templates',
        noRedeclare: true, 
        processName: function(filePath) {
          return declare.processNameByPath(filePath.replace('client/src/templates/', ''));
        }
      }));
```

I would then access templates through `appname.templates` array. It was working fine.

Now, I am moving to Webpack. If I use the [handlebars-loader](https://github.com/pcardune/handlebars-loader) , 
it allows me to require every template by name like

```
var template = require("./file.handlebars");
```

Is there a way to get all templates in one directory as an array like

```
var templates = require("./*.handlebars");
```

Comment: Maybe https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob-loader is what you want?

Comment: @bejado - Tx of pointing to glob loader. Yes, it loads dir of files, but I would need to apply handlebars loader also. Is there a way to call both. Also I am not sure how to import in code. Let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually would go to the folder you have your templates and have an `templates/index.js` file such as:

```
export templateA from './templateA.handlebars'
export templateB from './templateB.handlebars'
export templateC from './templateC.handlebars'
...
```

Then you can do:

```
import * as templates from './templates'
```

And `templates` is an object that holds all your templates. You can also do `templates.templateA` to access them by name.

Comment: Thanks albertfdp for the great solution. Works perfectly. In my project, I have not enabled Babel and so I have to write it as `export {default as templateA} from 'templateA.handlebars'`. Info on the syntax was from the link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35665759/es6-how-can-you-export-an-imported-module-in-a-single-line)