# How to set relative path resolution based on 'dist' folder

Tags: javascript, node.js

When creating a npm package, it is quite common and convenient to structure it like so:

```
root
  / dist
  / src
  / package.json
```

where `package.json`:

```
{
  "main": "dist/index.js"
  "files": [ "dist" ]
}
```

The drawback of this approach is, when consumer wants to require files using relative path, it needs to include the `dist` folder. E.g. `const abc = require('my-package/dist/x/y/abc');`

Is there a way to tell NodeJS to resolve relative path based on `path.dirname(main)` or something similar?

UPDATE: to clarify, this is related to relative/deep resolution, not about export hoisting in ES6.
It is a controversial subject that should this be done at all, as the consumer is coupled to the internal folder structure of the package.

UPDATE 2: what I want to achieve is a concept of "sub-module" (similar to namespacing). For example, my folder structure looks like this:

```
root
  / dist
     / testUtil.js
     / index.js
```

`testUtil.js` contains useful functions for testing. Since it is not used in normal use, I don't want to export them at top-level. i.e., instead of:

```
// index.js
export * from './testUtil'
```

I would do:

```
// index.js
import * as testUtil from './testUtil'
export { testUtil }
```

However, that still expose the `testUtil` module namespace at top-level and it is hard to use:

```
// consuming.js
import { testUtil } from 'my-package'
const { funcA, funcB } = testUtil
```

It would be better if I can "tug" it under a relative path:

```
// consuming.js
import { funcA, funcB } from 'my-package/testUtil'
```

Currently, without solving the 'dist' issue, I have to do this instead:

```
// consuming.js
import { funcA, funcB } from 'my-package/dist/testUtil'
```

Comment: You could just publish the `dist` directory.

Comment: Do you mean create a copy of `package.json` inside `dist`? This mean I have to sync the `dependencies` and copy part of the scripts such as `install`, `prepare`, `publish`, `version`, etc?

Comment: Yeah. It'd be more cumbersome but it would leave you with a much "cleaner" package. You could probably just have a `package.dist.json` that you copy and rename as a build step. Although your distributed version probably would have far fewer scripts; it would really just need an install and run script.

Answer (score 2):

You can set your `NODE_PATH` environment variable, and that should do the trick:

```
export NODE_PATH=./dist
```

There are some other patterns you could try out [here](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520).

Comment: This is a global env and for applications. The question is for module. But +1 for the link. :)

Answer (score 0):

Usual way is to export lots of stuff from within your "dist/index.js" file, rather than getting people to import other files. You can re-export stuff like this:

```
export { default as Something } from './something.js'
export SomethingElse from './something-else.js'
```

See this answer for more: [ES6, how can you export an imported module in a single line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35665759/es6-how-can-you-export-an-imported-module-in-a-single-line)

Comment: Yes. That is a good approach on ES6. The OP is about relative path resolution, which is a controversial subject.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the `dist` folder issue, you could publish your `dist` directory as a standalone package. This would involve maintaining a separate `package.json` (it would most likely be a much slimmer `package.json` compared to your source package).

For the sub-module/namespacing issue, I don't see the problem.

Given a package with the directory structure:

```
root
  / index.js
  / testUtils.js
  / utilities
    / index.js
    / calculator.js
    / worker.js
```

You can access the normal top-level exports with `require("root")`.

You can access `testUtils` with `require("root/testUtils")`.

You can access the top-level `utilities` module with `require("root/utilities")`.

You can access `calculator` with `require("root/utilities/calculator")`.

It's just up to you to maintain this structure in the way you want to expose to your consumers.