# import and export module in same file

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

Does anyone know of a better way to do this?

The goal: import, use, and export `createLogger` from the same file (application entry point).

WebStorm gives me a duplicate declaration warning.

```
import createLogger from './logger';

const logger = createLogger('namespace');

export { default as createLogger };
export { * as plugins } from './plugins'; 

export setup = () => {
  // ...
  logger.log('');
}

export start = async () => {
  // ... 
  logger.log('');
}
```

Comment: why do you want to import and export? you're not even modifying it

Comment: @Shane Exactly what are you trying to achieve? maybe there is another option for doing it because this seems weird...

Comment: you still don't need to export it, other places that need the `createLogger` can import it from the original logger file

Comment: Technically, yes, but this is for a library so we want to have everything importable from one statement. 

import { setup, start, createLogger } from 'library';

Comment: I see, so you can just do `export createLogger` I'm guessing? why the default? if it's default, the import would be `import createLogger, { setup, etc.. } from library` Also, the syntax might be wrong, it may have to be `export { createLogger as default }` instead of the other way around - scratch that, the syntax is right

Comment: have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35665759/es6-how-can-you-export-an-imported-module-in-a-single-line looks like it's `export { default as createLogger } from '...';` or you might be able to just do `export default createLogger;`

Comment: @ShaneDaugherty Did any of the responses help you? if you need more information we are here to help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To export multiple functions from the same file just do this:

```
import createLogger from './logger';
const logger = createLogger('namespace');
import plugins from './plugins';
import anotherLib from './anotherLib';

const setup = () => {
    // ...
    logger.log('');
}

const start = async () => {
    // ...
    logger.log('');
}


// export everything without default
export { plugins, 
    createLogger, 
    anotherLib,
    setup,
    start}
```

You can import them in another file after this is done.

Here's a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/q9mloq731w) to see how it works.

Have a look at [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) about the export statement.

Comment: This is just awesome.